# Mandar os dados de um tabela para outra

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony-2

E o seguinte, eu tenho um entity chamada Posto em que existe o registo de um posto e tenho uma entity chamada Maquina. 
O objectivo é:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ter uma tabela igual a esta onde criamos uma maquina e nos botões onde está ver e editar em vez desses vai ter um de converter. Quando carregamos ai a linha passa da entity posto para entity maquina.

O código que eu já tenho é o seguinte:
Isto na entity Maquina.new
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E na MaquinaController:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas dá-me erro.

Fiz um printscrm ao ecrã para você poder ver melhor o erro que me aparece.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e adicione seu código diretamente. Da forma que está fica difícil de visualizar.

Comment: Qual é o erro que acontece?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendi, você está querendo converter uma entidade do tipo `Posto` para uma entidade do tipo `Maquina`, certo?

No seu método `createAction` você está instanciando uma entidade do tipo `Maquina` sem preencher todos os valores dela. E a tabela existe que alguns valores sejam não-nulos, como acusa o erro que você postou.

A meu ver, o método deveria ser algo assim:

```
public function createAction($id)
{
    $posto = $this->getDoctrine()->getPostoRepository()->find($id);

    $maquina = new Maquina();
    $maquina->setNumero( $posto->getNumero() );
    $maquina->setDescricao( $posto->getNumero() );
    $maquina->setEndereco( $posto->getNumero() );
    $maquina->setestacao( $posto->getNumero() );
    $maquina->setProtocolo( $posto->getNumero() );
    $maquina->setAtivo( $posto->getNumero() );
    $maquina->setLer( $posto->getNumero() );
    $maquina->setDtype('maquina');

    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($maquina);
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('manutencao_maquina', array('id' => $id)));
}
```